# How to get all futuers of current user?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to get all property of current user? (in asp.net membership)

I want get Name , Email , Pic and property of current user.

Comment: you need to put all of the properties you want to user`s `session`, and get those when you want

Comment: "futuers", what is that?

Comment: put to user`s session like this : `HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("UserID", "every thing you want");` and get by this `HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"]`

Comment: just notice you have to `cast`, when you get objects from `session` to their types

Comment: I am use aspnet_membership. how to add or update more property for user to membership?

Comment: `aspnet_membership` has special classes to achieve this, follow msdn

Comment: but i cant change these

Comment: try like this `MembershipUser SomeUser = Membership.GetUser("SomeUserName");
            SomeUser.Email = "email address";
            Membership.UpdateUser(SomeUser);` to add more property, i think you need to add them to `webconfig`

Comment: have you read documentation about `asp membership` yet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use :

```
User.Identity.Name
```

or to access it elsewhere:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

Then to get email etc:

```
string email = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name).Email;
```

Comment: ok , tanks. How to add or update more property in aspnet_membership?

Comment: try this tutorial it tells you how to add new fields to registration form http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/101106-1.aspx